# SIPREC Protocol with FREESWITCH

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch, rfc, call-recording

I was trying to enable call-recording in VOIP calls so i read about the SIPREC
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc7866.html
How to use **SIPREC** protocol with FREESWITCH??is there any module for that??
please gives me your valuable suggestion with respect of SIPREC Protocol only ,the prime requirement is call record not happened on same server(freewitch) RTP will be send to the another call-recording server

Comment: Did you found any solution for this in past one year?